# display data from two datarows c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datarow

I have two datarows. I make some select in both:

```
DataRow[] result1 = MainWindow.dt.Select("number ='" + num_int + "' and Group ="'+ group + '"");
DataRow[] result2 = MainWindow.listUlg.Select("Ulg ='" +row[17]+"'");
```

I get from result1 :

```
group1 2  Name1

group2 3  Name2

group3 4  Name3
```

and form result2:

```
3 tarif1

2 tarif2
```

I would like to display tarif2 + Name2 and tarif1 + Name1.
I try with some foreach loop but i doesn't work properly especialy when the sequence is different

```
DataRow[] result1 = MainWindow.dt.Select("number ='" + num_int + "' and Group ="'+group + '"");
foreach (var row in result1)
{

  DataRow[] result2 = MainWindow.listUlg.Select("Ulg ='" +row[17]+"'");

  foreach (var row2 in result2)
  {
     MessageBox.Show(row[2] +" "+ row2[1] )
  }
}
```

Comment: "I would like to display tarif2 + Name2 and tarif1 + Name1" - Why?  What are the rules that would imply tarif2 goes with Name2 and tarif1 goes with Name1?  Is it the order in the list?  Something else?  (If it is just the order in the list then use the linq Zip function.)

Comment: Yes it is the right order

Comment: Your response makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you have to loop through the array having ***minimum*** length. Then just extract the elements and concatenate them normally:

```
//This is your intial data which depends on the num_int and row[17]
DataRow[] result1 = MainWindow.dt.Select("number ='" + num_int + "' and Group ="'+group + '"");
DataRow[] result2 = MainWindow.listUlg.Select("Ulg ='" +row[17]+"'");

for(var i = 0; i < Math.Min(result1.Length, result2.Length); i++){
   MessageBox.Show(result2[i][1] + " " + result1[i][2]);
}
```

Comment: if i change order in datarows i get the same problem.

Comment: @user3455769 could you elaborate on the exact problem? your code will print some duplicated result (and it is of course not what you want), so I don't even know the problem you mean here (it is certainly not the problem produced by your own code).

Comment: @user3455769 you're welcome, I was not sure if this actually answered your question, but responses from the OP are needed to improve the answers. Also if it's helpful, just accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a key to associate rows in data set one and rows in data set two, something like an foreign key. As you have already figured, using the order to figure which one match which will not work.

So assuming you modify your data model and add a foreign key, thing will get easier. You can do it just like:

```
DataRow[] result1 = MainWindow.dt.Select("number ='" + num_int + "' and Group ="'+group + '"");
DataRow[] result2 = MainWindow.listUlg.Select("Ulg ='" +row[17]+"'");

foreach (var row in result1)
{

    string output=row[2];

    if(result2.Where(x=>x.id=row.id).Count()>0)
    {
    var row2 = result2.Where(x=>x.id=row.id).First();
    output+=" "+row2[1];
    }


    MessageBox.Show(output);

}
```